# Qt paint on a popup window with data from database

Tags: qt

In Qt GUI application, I made a dialog containing a table. When I double click a row in the table, I want:

1. a popup window to show up;
2. get points data according to that row from a database;
3. plot those points on the popup window.

I've done the fetch function of points data in a database.cpp. But according to the rule, the plotting function has to be in dialog.cpp, in a void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) function. Can I do the plotting function lineTo() in that database.cpp data fetch function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paint in a `QPixmap` from anywhere, and pass that pixmap to the popup dialog to be displayed inside a `QLabel` or painted by the `paintEvent` function.

You can also use `QPolygonF` which has the advantage of being more cleanly scalable.

Look at the function `generatePixmap` in [that article](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq12-qpixmapcache.html) (Qt Quaterly), then use [`QLabel::setPixmap`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) to assign the pixmap to the label.

Comment: Thank you, I will try QPixmap. When I google QPixmap, there is no obvious example showing how to use both QPixmap and QLabel to draw (x,y) data points. Do you know any source to show good example? Thank you.

Comment: @Sean I added a link with some examples.